# How to toggle on/off the OSM layer in the online editor?

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to toggle on/off the OSM layer to see what is in the Bing aerial image.

How to do that in the OSM online editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find an option to disable the data layer completely. But you can select *Map Data* in the panel on the right (shortcut F), open *Map Features* and disable individual features you don't want to see.

Note: Such questions are better suited at http://help.openstreetmap.org.